# Having gradient on text on gradient background

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add gradient to text cross browser?
I want to have gradient colored text on gradient background.
I have a `h1` that should be colored with gradient and also have gradient background. That's why `-webkit-mask-image` or `-moz-mask-image` wont work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've developed a function that replace texts with canvas and it allow you to add gradient colors via CSS color property. Take a look at it and let me know if you like it.

https://github.com/mohsen1/Gradient-for-text